# second derivative of product of Jacobi with geodesic is ill

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a Jacobi field $J$ along a geodesic $\gamma$ and a metric $g$. How do I show the following.

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}g(J_t,\dot{\gamma}(t)) = 0$$

Since the connexion is compatible, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}g(J_t,\dot{\gamma}(t)) = g(\nabla_\dot{\gamma}J,\dot{\gamma}) + g(J,\nabla_\dot{\gamma}\dot{\gamma}) = g(\nabla_\dot{\gamma}J,\dot{\gamma})$$
so second derivative is $g(\nabla_\dot{\gamma}(\nabla_\dot{\gamma}J),\dot{\gamma})$

but after that I am always turning in circles to try and find something that is zero.

Comment: sorry, second derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J=J(t)$ be a Jacobi vector field along $\gamma$.

Denote $J'=D_t (J)$ and $J''=D^{2}_{t}J$

Now
\begin{align}
D^{2}_{t} \langle J, \gamma' \rangle &= \langle J''(t), \gamma' \rangle \\
&= - \langle R(J, \gamma')\gamma',\gamma' \rangle \\
&= -R(J, \gamma', \gamma', \gamma') \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: I don't get $<J''(t),\gamma'> = -<R(J,\gamma')\gamma',\gamma'>$

Comment: This comes from the fact that  vector field $J$ is a *Jacobi field* if it satisfies Jacobi's equation $$J''(t) + R(J(t), \gamma'(t))\gamma'(t)=0$$

Comment: duh. obviously :) sorry I should have seen that

Comment: @tomak No problem, I probably should have been clearer!

Comment: You just need to add the word "Jacobi" to the first line of your answer.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Good spot, changed accordingly.